# How to send 3 mails using 3 differents gmail address to the same user using gmail api

Tags: gmail

3 différents people in my compagny need to send the same e-mail every time their is someone new.

What's the best wait to send this email using gmail

From what i saw they need to give me their password. Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. If you write a program and it has a configuration file, then the email address can be defined in the configuration file. You can then hand over the program to the others, who will use it on their own, changing their credentials in the configuration files.

Comment: It seems that it doesn't work with nodemailer and gmail

Comment: @sliprose I am sure this is solvable. I am not really experienced in NodeJS, but I have solved similar things using other technologies. I am sure you can achieve this using NodeJS as well. Can you show us what and how did you try?

Comment: I found the solution by calling google
You need to go to your gmail parameters and add the other address in the 'as' section then you can send email with as this address mail using gmail